# Javascript closure and setTImeInterval function

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
function sampleDelay(delay) {
  return function(functionArray) {
    var count = 0;
    var func = setInterval(function(){
    if(count === functionArray.length){
      clearInterval(func);  
    }
          count++;
    console.log(functionArray[count-1]);
      return functionArray[count-1];        
    }, delay);

  };
}


var DelayedValue = sampleDelay(1000)([
  1,2,3,4,5
]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the values of DelayedValue varibale to be 1,2,3,4,5 after a delay of one second.
This code is not returning values of DelayedValue variable.

Please suggest what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: You have a syntax error on your `sampleDelay` function, on your `console.log` statment...

Comment: This is a strange mix of smart patterns and wtf. Why does the function you pass to setInterval return an array ?

Comment: removed the extra semicolon which is causing the error.

Comment: @dystroy : because i want the elements of array to be returned every time when setInterval function has been called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you made your code asynchronous by introducing the interval. Your function already finished executing while the interval is still running. You need to work with callbacks and/or promises to solve this.

You can do it like this for example ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6N8fz/)):

```
function delayedOutput(values, delay, callback){
    var step = 0,
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            callback(values[step++]);

            if(step === values.length){
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
    }, delay); 
}

delayedOutput([1,2,3,4,5], 1000, function(i){
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += i;
});
```

Comment: can you please suggest what could be the exact call back function, i tried but not able to fix it.